# How to Store different language(non english) data in MongoDB Field and retrive the same data?

Tags: python, mongodb, encoding, utf-8, pymongo

I am tring to store non english(like: Bengali,Hindi) data in a MongoDB field.

```
This is my approach:-

import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.testdb

db['testing'].save({'data':'শুভ নববর্ষ'})
```

I got an Exception.
    Exception Value: Non-ASCII character '\xe0' in file /test/views.py on line 5, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details (views.py, line 5)

After that I have tried like this:-

```
from bson import BSON
bson_string = BSON.encode({'data':'শুভ নববর্ষ'})
db['testing'].save({'data':'শুভ নববর্ষ'})
```

This time also I got the same error.

Edit:-
basically i am not able to `print 'শুভ নববর্ষ'`  in `IDLE`

```
>>>print 'শুভ নববর্ষ'
Unsupported characters in input
```

### `1ST EDIT` :-

I have added `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in my views.py then able to store the data somehow.
 But this object structure is not same with the normal data structure in mongodb.
 Like:-

```
> db['testing'].find()
{à¦·" } : ObjectId("52d65a50012bad0b23c13a65"), "data" : "à¦¶à§à¦­ à¦¨à¦¬à¦¬à¦°à


I have added another record.
>db['testing'].save({'data':'kousik chowdhury'})

Now the collection is looking funny.
> db['testing'].find()                                                           à¦·" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d65e6a012bad0a39a2685b"), "data" : "kousik chowdhury" }¦°à§

> db['testing'].find().length()
2
```

### Data Retrive :-

```
** I am using PuTTY as a editor. 

>>> a = db['testing'].find()[0]
>>> a
{u'_id': ObjectId('52d65a50012bad0b23c13a65'), u'data': u'\u09b6\u09c1\u09ad\u09a8\u09ac\u09ac\u09b0\u09cd\u09b7'}
>>> mydata = a['data']
>>>mydata
u'\u09b6\u09c1\u09ad \u09a8\u09ac\u09ac\u09b0\u09cd\u09b7'
>>>mydata.encode('utf-8')
'\xe0\xa6\xb6\xe0\xa7\x81\xe0\xa6\xad \xe0\xa6\xa8\xe0\xa6\xac\xe0\xa6\xac\xe0\xa6\xb0\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\xb7'
```

Is there any standard process so that I can store it in mongodb in proper format and get the data back ?

Comment: Your first approach looks correct to me, and it works when I try it.

Comment: Does it work when you explicitly use a unicode string literal? e.g. db['testing'].save({'data':u'শুভ নববর্ষ'})

Comment: got 'Unsupported characters in input' in idle

Comment: In your second code fragment, line 3, I think you meant to use db['testing'].save({'data': bson_string}) ... however, both methods should work - I tested them both in python 2.7 and 3.3

Comment: I am using 2.7.For me i am not able to print this 'শুভ নববর্ষ'.Got 'Unsupported characters in input' in idle

Comment: @Mzzl Did you check with the same input like this {'data':'শুভ নববর্ষ'}?

Comment: Yeah, I copy&pasted it from this page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have line:

```
# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-
```

on the beginning of your file?
For example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

PART 2:

- saving data use unicode prefix (u'')
- assuming you wanted to do a['data'].encode('utf-8') it works correctly - just

  print a['data'].encode('utf-8')

HINT: There is never a good reason to override basic type with some value... (I mean str='')

Comment: I am trying to do this in idle.

Comment: Idle bases on your windows locale settings and it is not possible to change it to utf-8... 
You may edit IOBinding.py in $python/idellib and force set encoding to utf-8 - for example around line 43...
Solution from http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/543035-typing-utf-8-characters-idle

But I would not recommend it... it may affect some other things...

Comment: thanks for the reply.I appriciate your answer.I have edited the question please check it.

Comment: Updated my answer, if you get u'\u09b6\u09c1\u09ad \u09a8\u09ac\u09ac\u09b0\u09cd\u09b7' decode it as utf-8 and print it

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in iTerm on Mac:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient().test
db.test_collection.drop()
db.test_collection.save({'data': 'শুভ নববর্ষ'})
document = db.test_collection.find_one()
print document['data']
```

The printed output matches the input: শুভ নববর্ষ.

MongoDB itself expects all text to be encoded as UTF-8, so it supports all unicode text. The trouble you're having is finding a way to **print** the output when you retrieve it, in IDLE or anywhere else. Try running your script in the Windows command prompt and see if the output renders correctly there.

Comment: Oh: happy new year to you, too!

Comment: I am geting this u'\u09b6\u09c1\u09ad \u09a8\u09ac\u09ac\u09b0\u09cd\u09b7'

Comment: @ A. Jesse Jiryu Davis ধন্যবাদ