# Mongo DB Save Hindi Text with PHP script

Tags: php, mongodb, utf-8

I am looking the solution to save "Hindi" font in Mongo DB but nothing found.I have tried to below code but this is also not working

```
$title = mb_convert_encoding($title, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1");
```

I have also followed below link but its not working

[How to Store different language(non english) data in MongoDB Field and retrive the same data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085939/how-to-store-different-languagenon-english-data-in-mongodb-field-and-retrive-t)

Please help me if anyone have idea.I have spent more than 3 to 4 hours but not working.

Comment: Do you start out with `ISO-8859-1` encoding? If so that is your problem. You need UTF8 through the whole process.

Comment: @user3783243,I have also tried without ISO-8859-1 and only put UTF8 ,still not working,can you please let me know how to change database UTF?actually I am not able to save Hindi font with GUI tool also.

Comment: If the webpage is in ISO-8859-1 you need to change that to UTF8.

Comment: @user3783243,I have already tried this as said in earlier comment.